# Vuejs share library with multiple components

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I'm using Vue together with Firebase. I'm initialising using the following code

Index.vue

```
import Firebase from 'firebase';
import User from './User';


export default {
    components: {
        User
    },
    data() {
        return {
            users: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        let firebase = Firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: "blablabla",
        });

        firebase.database().ref('users').on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
            this.users.unshift(user);
        });
    }
}
```

This is all working fine. Now in another component, when I want to save a new entity to the Firebase, I run almost the same code to initialise the library.

Create.vue

```
import Firebase from 'firebase';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            name: '',
            tagid: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        createUser() {

            let firebase = Firebase.initializeApp({
                apiKey: "blablabla",
            });

            firebase.database().child('users').push({
                name: this.name,
                tagid: this.tagid
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now obviously I'm getting an error, and it's also duplicate work. But I'm wondering.

> How can I share the initialisation of the Firebase plugin with all the components that need it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do not inicialize it in component, but in Vue instance and pass it to components as prop. Or hold it in Vuex.

```
<div id="app">
  <component :fb="instance"></component>
</div>

<template id="component">
  ...
</component>

<script>
  Vue.component('comp-one', {
    template: '#comp-one',
    props: ['fb'],
    methods: {
      createUser () {
        this.fb.database().child('users').push({
          name: this.name,
          tagid: this.tagid
        })
      }
    }
  })

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      instance: null
    },
    created () {
      this.instance = Firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "blablabla"
      })
    }
  })
</script>
```

So, in main.js edit this:

```
new Vue({
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

to this:

```
new Vue({
  template: '<App/>',
  data: {
    instance: null
  },
  created () {
    this.instance = Firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "blablabla"
    })
  }
})
```

Just do not forget to add prop to html:

```
<my-component :fb="instance">
```

And in component definition:

```
import Firebase from 'firebase';

export default {
  props: ['fb'],
  data () {
    return {
      name: '',
      tagid: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createUser() {
      this.fb.database().child('users').push({
        name: this.name,
        tagid: this.tagid
      })
    }
  }
}
```

And repeat this with all all your components, which use firebase.

Comment: In my main.js i'm using new Vue({template: '<App/>'}). Do i need to pass something else because I'm getting fb not found in my app.vue. Thank you!

Comment: @Notflip Are you using Vuex?

Comment: Nope. I'm not, is that needed?

Comment: @Notflip Not needed, but better. Wait, I edit the answer.

Comment: Vue js plugins are an option here. There is already one for firebase: https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire. The vuejs docs include an example based on this plugin: https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/firebase.html